# Ubuntu dock seems to have lost performance

Tags: ubuntu-dock, gnome-shell-extension

Versions

- Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 64 Bits
- GNOME 3.36.8

When showing/hiding active apps' icons the dock seems to have lost its usual performance.

This process happened seamlessly until yesterday. I don't remember having done any dramatic changes recently.

I must mention that it also wasn't showing the icons. So I decided to give `sudo apt reinstall gnome-shell` a go and they are now on the dock but it takes 23 seconds or so for them to appear. This is unusual in comparison to the other processes of the interface, which happen seamlessly.

**UPDATE:**

As I was recording this issue, I've noticed that now the apps are not appearing on the dock again, so a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXue2.jpg) will do to show the bug.

Comment: Can you add a video of this performance to your

Comment: I have added an image.